# yii CDbCriteria and subquery in join statment

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am quite new in Yii and I have something like that:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
...
...
$criteria->alias = 'l'; 
$criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT nip as tab_nip FROM licenses UNION SELECT DISTINCT nip FROM orders) as tab ON (tab.tab_nip = l.nip)';
$criteria->join .= ' LEFT JOIN products p ON l.product_id=p.id';
$criteria->join .= ' LEFT JOIN sticky_notes sn ON l.last_sticky_note_id';
```

And then

```
self::model()->with('product')->findAll($criteria); // self it's model class for table with l alias
```

I get results but I can't get access to tab.tab_nip. What's wrong here ? Can't I use this expresssion ? Should I use

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

OK I've solved it.
I added public attribute tap_nip in my Model Class and now it works as I want.